# run exe from python gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, exe

I have got an EXE file that lunch the ms-dos prompt and ask for several input parameter, which can be provided either as input one by one (var1 --> enter, var2 --> enter and so on) or as an array. Then it makes some calculation and creates a TXT file as output.

I want to launch the EXE from python, and provide the input parameters via a gui in python to the ms-dos prompt (this is my main concern) and run the simulation (via a start button in the gui). Any idea? Is it possible?

Here is something I started with:

```
import os

from Tkinter import Tk     # from tkinter import Tk for Python 3.x
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
filename = askopenfilename("file.exe") # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file

os.system(filename)
```

Comment: For the input parameters, you will have to design the GUI yourself. It will take a bit of work for designing it an it doesn't seem like it's a good stackoverflow question. If you have a specific `tkinter` question, I will be happy to try to answer it.

Comment: @TheLizzard thanks for the feedback. actually my main concern is about the input parameters. could you provide me with some reference? I'd like to take a shot. Thanks

Comment: I don't know any pre built packages that you can use for that part of the GUI, but I recommend looking at some `tkinter` tutorials. After that, if you have a specific question, ask. The question right now is too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: I agree with @TheLizzard, this would be an excellent way to learn how to use `tkinter` because what you want to do is relatively straightforward. Essentially all you need is a single window with some entry fields and a "Submit"  button to launch the EXE and pass it the input values entered by the user.

Comment: This tutorial titled [Simple registration form using Python Tkinter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/simple-registration-form-using-python-tkinter). Looks like it would give you a good start. There are many others on the web if you google for them.

Answer (score 0):

### Subprocess

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call([r"tools/external_tools/mintty.exe", "-t", "Terminal", "-i", "icon.ico"])

# subprocess.check_call([r".exe", "argument", "argument_parameter"])
```

If it is implemented like this, every time it is run, the program will stop responding. Hence it is recommended you do this with threading

### With Threading

```py
import subprocess
import threading

def custom_terminal():
    subprocess.check_call([r"tools/external_tools/mintty.exe", "-t", "Terminal", "-i", "icon.ico"])

threader = threading.Thread(target=custom_terminal)
threader.start()
```